# Checking if array length is a perfect square

Tags: java, arrays, perfect-square

I am trying to write an if statement to check to see if the amount of numbers a user enters into the array is a perfect square (4, 9, 25, 36...).

```
if(array.length != Math.sqrt(array))
```

I know this isn't correct and I know it is probably something easy, but I can't seem to get how to think of an if statement to see if my array is a number that is a perfect square.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919111/whats-the-best-way-in-javascript-to-test-if-a-given-parameter-is-a-square-numbe

Comment: if(issquare(array.length))

will evaluate true of the length of the array is a square.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int root = (int)Math.sqrt(array.length);
boolean isSquare = root * root == array.length;
```

Or

```
if ((int)Math.sqrt(array.length) == Math.sqrt(array.length))
```

There are other ways too, but they all would employ the fact that the square root should be a whole number.

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the equality check.

Comment: @theo quite so. Thanks for picking it up ( fixed now)

Answer (score 0):

There are similar answers for other languages, but this algorithm should work with what you're doing:

```
bool IsPerfectSquare(long input)
{
    long SquareRoot = (long) Math.Sqrt(input);
    return ((SquareRoot * SquareRoot) == input);
}
```

see this link for more info:

[What's a good algorithm to determine if an input is a perfect square?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343852/whats-a-good-algorithm-to-determine-if-an-input-is-a-perfect-square)

Comment: This is another great way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862637/perfect-square-or-not